# Determinant of a complex matrice

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying to get into a Master's degree in Pure Mathematics in Brazil and I came across this question:

**Let $n \geq 1$ a natural number, $a$ be a real number, $(w_1, ..., w_n)$ be a vector of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $A = A(a,w_1, ...,w_n)$ a complex matrix defined by**

$$[A] \ = \ \begin{bmatrix} 
a - \lvert w_1\rvert^2 & - \overline{w_1}w_2 &  \ldots & -\overline{w_1}w_n\\
-\overline{w_2}w_1 & a - \lvert w_2 \rvert^2 & \ldots & - \overline{w_2}w_n\\[2pt]
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\[6pt]
-\overline{w_n}w_1 & -\overline{w_n}w_2 & \ldots & a - \lvert w_n\rvert^2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

My idea is proof by induction on the order of matrice that
$$
\det A \,=\, a^n - a^{n-1}\bigg(\sum_{i = 1}^n \, \lvert w_i \rvert^2 \bigg).
$$

I tested the cases $n = 2,3$. **Any suggestions on how to prove the $n + 1$ case?**

Comment: The standard way to compute an n x n determinant lends itself naturally to induction,

Comment: @Divide1918 Exactly. I would like suggestions on how to prove the general case.

Comment: Note that $A$ is a rank-1 perturbation of $aI$.  Now use the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one direct way to calculate the determinant. Let $w = (\overline{w_1},\dots, \overline{w_n})^T \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and let $B=ww^{\ast} \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times x}$ where $w^\ast$ denotes the conjugate transpose (i.e $w^\ast = (w_1,\dots, w_n)$). The key observation is that $\det(A)$ is just the characteristic polynomial $p_B(a)$ of $B$. Also, notice that $w^\ast w = |w_1|^2+\dots+|w_n|^2$. Now it's just a matter of putting everything together!

First, verify that $w$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $|w_1|^2+\dots+|w_n|^2$. Indeed,

$$Bw=ww^\ast w=(|w_1|^2+\dots+|w_n|^2)w$$
Now, if $v$ is perpendicular to $w$ we have $w^\ast v=0$ so
$$Bv = ww^\ast v = 0$$
By picking an orthogonal basis containing $w$ we see that $B$ is similar to $\text{diag}(|w_1|^2+\dots+|w_n|^2, 0, \dots, 0)$. Since similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial we have
$$\det(A) = p_B(a) =a^{n-1}\left(a-\sum_{i=1}^n |w_i|^2\right)=a^n - a^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n |w_i|^2$$

Comment: Thank you very much!